# Is it possible to have Notepad++ show two rows of file tabs?

Tags: tabs, notepad++

Is it possible to have Notepad++ show two rows of file tabs?

I wasn't able to find such a setting.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

According to the [documentation Wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Tab_Bar):

- When more tabs that can fit on the
  view are displayed:

  - if Settings ->
    Preferences -> General -> Tab bar ->
    Multiline is checked, several rows of
    tabs will stack. Clicking on a tab
    brings to the bottommost row the
    whole row of tabs
  - Otherwise a pair of
    small buttons pointing left and right
    will show, and clicking them will
    move through the imaginary row of
    tabs. The triangles show up and down
    if the tabs are arrranged vertically.

This was definitely an SU question, not SO where they would have laughed and pointed and sent your question here.

Answer (score 15):

**STEP 1:** Settings -> Preferences...
Will open Preferences window.

**STEP 2:** Find the "**Tab Bar**" check-box group and check "**Multi-line**"

[image: **Picture illustrating steps:**]

Comment: What is the added value of this answer? It just seems to repeat the answer posted 7 years ago.

Comment: The picture supplied took me about 30 minutes to make. And I find I can digest information faster in illustration form. I found the main answer too verbose.

I personally prefer short concise answers when I am skimming, and only go to the longer answers when the shorter ones do not work.